# Codeigniter else section but throws an odd error

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
                <?php
                    $q3 = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM default_post_likes
                                            WHERE post_id = $row->id");
                    $row2 = $q3->row();
                    if ($row2->post_id == $row->id) {
                        echo 'Unlike';
                    } else {
                        echo '<a class="like" posterid="'.$row->creator_id.'" postid="'.$row->id.'" href="javascript:void(0)">Like</a>';
                    }
                ?>
```

For some reason the if portion works perfectly, but the else works and echo's out the data but throws an error. I get the following error in Codeigniter:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Trying to get property of non-object
>
> Filename: views/dashboard.php
>
> Line Number: 74

Any ideas?

Here is the rest of my code: http://pastebin.com/4nCzxfY3

Comment: I don't see where `$row` is defined.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4nCzxfY3

Comment: Why don't you first check if the two properties exist?

Comment: did you check the spelling of your column names?

Comment: I have. They are non existent in the else statement, but Like is still outputted in the browser.

Comment: Check for typos, check if the query should return any result (one row at least)

Answer (score 0):

You should figure out why are the properties missing (it's hard to help you more with the info you provided), but for a quick fix, this should do:

```
if ($row && $row2->post_id == $row->id) {
    echo 'Unlike';
} elseif ($row) {
    echo '<a class="like" posterid="'.$row->creator_id.'" postid="'.$row->id.'" href="javascript:void(0)">Like</a>';
}
```

I'd also avoid running two queries inside the foreach loop.

Comment: I've already the same thing and tested, doesn't work. Just throws the same error.

Comment: What other info do you need?

Comment: Ok, let's make it more strict. Try this.

Comment: But anyway, that won't solve the problem, just not echo the problematic line. I'd suggest you check for your row values in each iteration and see what happens there.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...

```
echo '<a class="like" posterid="'.$row[creator_id].'" postid="'.$row[id].'"
  href="javascript:void(0)">Like</a>';
```